# Object's variable ceases to exist out of scope

Tags: c++, scope

So I'm working on creating a poker game, and I need to create a player and assign it a name, and then push a pointer to that player into a vector. But when the name goes out of scope, the player ceases to have a name, even though the name has already been assigned.

```
void Game::add_player(string& playerName) {
    Player* finder = find_player(playerName);
    if (finder == NULL) {
        char * nameAsCharArray = new char[playerName.length() + NEXT_TO];
        strcpy_s(nameAsCharArray, playerName.length() + NEXT_TO, playerName.c_str());
        char * name = nameAsCharArray;
        Player player = Player::Player(name);
        Player * p(&player);
        players.push_back(p);
    }
    else {
        throw ALREADY_PLAYING;
    }
}
```

When the code hits the else statement, the name assigned to the player ceases to exist.

Comment: `player` is gone. Any pointer to it is left dangling.

Comment: It would be best for your vector to hold real objects of `player` and not pointers.

Comment: Adding on to what chris said, even though you create a pointer to your player (by getting its reference) that doesn't allow it to exist beyond the scope of the function. Your pointer is pointing at junk after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    Player player = Player::Player(name);
    Player * p(&player);
    players.push_back(p);
```

use

```
    Player* p = new Player(name);
    players.push_back(p);
```

Since you are in C++ land, why are still managing memory for `char*` anyway? Change your class to use `std::string`.